# String Rotation program in Java to find the number of spaces rotated backwards

Tags: java

> Write a function that receives two strings and returns n, where n is
>   equal to the number of characters we should shift the first string
>   forward to match the second.
>
> For instance, take the strings "fatigue" and "tiguefa". In this case,
>   the first string has been rotated 5 characters forward to produce the
>   second string, so 5 would be returned.
>
> If the second string isn't a valid rotation of the first string, the
>   method returns -1. Examples:
>
> ```
> "coffee", "eecoff" => 2 , i got -1
> "eecoff", "coffee" => 4 
> "moose", "Moose" => -1 
> "isn't", "'tisn" => 2 
> "Esham", "Esham" => 0 
> "dog", "god" => -1
> ```

My code here is not giving me the good results : I got `-1` everytime

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (args.length < 2) {
        System.out.println("Please specify two strings to compare");
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    char[] firstArr = args[0].toCharArray();
    char[] secondArr = args[1].toCharArray();

    if (firstArr.length != secondArr.length) {
        System.out.println(args[0] + ", " + args[1] + " => -1");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < firstArr.length; i++) {
        boolean matches = true;
        for (int j = 0; j < firstArr.length; j++) {
            if (firstArr[i] != secondArr[(j + i) % firstArr.length]) {
                matches = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (matches == true) {
            System.out.println(args[0] + ", " + args[1] + " => " + i);
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(args[0] + ", " + args[1] + " => -1");
}
```

Comment: What is your *question*? Please take the [tour] and review [ask].

Comment: @azro *"not giving me the good results"* is **not** a [mcve].

Comment: @jonrsharpe we have its code, and its tests and expected result. I debugged its code, it'll correct him, and show him an easier way

Comment: @azro but we don't have the *actual result*, i.e. which of those test cases it fails for and how.

Comment: @JakePalmer1969 As you'll read the comments you'll understand that a good question requires : tests inputs + expected result + actual results, you were close to this time, you'll improve next time I'm sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has an error, explained at the end of my answer, below is more simple version solution

---

- a method to rotate
- a method to test the rotations

```
public static int rotateIndex(String s1, String s2) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= s2.length(); i++) {
        if (rotate(s2, i).equals(s1)) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

public static String rotate(String s, int offset) {
    int i = offset % s.length();
    return s.substring(i) + s.substring(0, i);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (args.length < 2) {
        System.out.println("Please specify two strings to compare");
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    int result = rotateIndex(args[0], args[1]);
    System.out.println(args[0] + ", " + args[1] + " => " + result);
}
```

---

Correction of OP's code : the inedx for `firstArr` should be `j`, the `i` is the rotation index to use on `secondArr`

```
for (int i = 0; i < firstArr.length; i++) {
    boolean matches = true;
    for (int j = 0; j < firstArr.length; j++) {
        if (firstArr[j] != secondArr[(i + j) % firstArr.length]) {
            matches = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (matches) {
        System.out.println(args[0] + ", " + args[1] + " 1 => " + i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To find the if a string is a rotation of another, just append one string to itself and then find where the indices match.

```java
String a = "coffee";
String b = "eecoff";
int index = (a.length() != b.length()) ? -1 : (b + b).indexOf(a);
```

Comment: I like the idea, but you need to do it both ways. `a="c"` would be a rotation with this single-shot approach.

Comment: Fixed it to make sure both strings start with the same lengths.

Answer (score 0):

Give the following data:

```
      Map<String,String> data = Map.of(
      "coffee", "eecoff"         ,
            "eecoff", "coffee"   ,
            "moose", "Moose"     ,
            "isn't", "'tisn"     ,
            "Esham", "Esham"     ,
            "dog", "god");
```

Simply iterate over the map.  A -1 indicates that no rotation satisfied the requirement.

```
     data.forEach((k,v)-> {
        String save = k;
        int count = 0;
        while (!k.equals(v)) {
           k = k.substring(1)+k.charAt(0);
           count++;
           if (count == k.length()) {
              count = -1;
              break;
           }
        }

        System.out.println(save + "  " + v + " => " + count);
     });
```